# Using delayed_paperclip in Sidekiq in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, sidekiq

I have an issue which is strangely not addressed anywhere.

I am using paperclip to upload attachments to S3 in a Heroku app. But since the upload takes time i started using delayed_paperclip. But the issue is the Sidekiq worker fails with a error message that 'unable to open the file or file not found'. This makes perfect sense as the heroku worker and web are running on different dynos.

Is there any solution to it? except that the web has to upload it to S3, which defeats the whole purpose.

The bottom line problem for me is I am unable to share files in tmp folder between the web and the worker

Comment: You've answered your own question.  You must use shared storage of some sort, S3 being most common because Heroku runs in EC2 already.

Comment: Yes, @MikePerham but i have to upload my image to S3 in a blocking call from the controller. I am ok if my sidekiq job takes a minute but not ok for the controller action being slow. Having said that it still is a good approach. thanks

Comment: There are ways to make the browser push the image to the S3 bucket directly, not through your Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

The upload process is not related to your Rails App at all, you are going to have improvements if processing the file is taking too much time, but in your case, the problem sounds like it's related to a big file and slow network

Comment: The bottom line problem for me is I am unable to share files in tmp folder between the web and the worker

Comment: Please see the answer of Mile Perham, you need to store the file on a service like Amazon S3, then, grab the url from sidekiq